# Changing Mac Hardware UUID on a Parallels 11 VM

Tags: macos, parallels

I have a few VMs in Parallels 11, running several different versions of OS X, for automated software builds.

I recently copied those VMs to a different host, so I'd have a second set to fall back on in case of a hardware failure.

The problem: the copied VMs have the same Hardware UUIDs as the corresponding originals, and that causes a problem backing up the VMs with Time Machine, since Time Machine links backup images to machines by their Hardware UUIDs. If you have two VMs with the same Hardware UUID, Time Machine running in those two VMs will try to write to the same sparsebundle file on the backup server.

I googled the issue and found this: http://kb.parallels.com/en/11197 -- but those instructions don't work for Parallels 11: when you double-click the pvm, it is imported immediately, without asking whether it was moved or copied. When I **first** imported the copies, Parallels asked me whether the VMs were moved or copied, and I answered that they were copied. The KB article makes it sound like that should have made Parallels assign new Hardware UUIDs to the VMs, but that didn't happen (it did assign new MAC addresses, though).

I'm going to try finding the Hardware UUID in the PVM using a hex search; if I can find it, maybe I can change it manually, using a hex editor. It seems like a very yucky procedure, though, for something you'd think Parallels should handle itself. Is there any better way of doing this? Is this a bug in Parallels 11, or did they deliberately remove the Hardware UUID reset functionality (and if so, why)?

Comment: Have you checked <machine>.pvm/config.pvs?  It's an xml config file, and on my (Parallels 10) VMs, there are several fields with "Uuid" in the name.  You might try playing with those. I haven't tried it, but I have had some success changing other parameters in that config file without breaking anything in the VM.

Comment: I found these fields with uuid in their names: VmUuid, SourceVmUuid, LinkedVmUuid, LinkedSnapshotUuid, ServerUuid, LastServerUuid, Uuid, TorbayUuid. None of them matched the VM's hardware UUID, as reported by Apple -> About This Mac -> System Report -> Hardware -> Hardware UUID.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No, I never did find the solution. I ended up deleting the VMs and creating new ones. The Parallels forum was no help, either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change it by:

1. Shutting down the virtual machine
2. Find the virtual machine bundle located on disk in Finder, right click on it and "Show package contents" on the actual .pvm file.
3. Then find the config.pvs file inside and open it with a text editor.
4. Change an arbitrary digit in the `<SourceVmUuid>`
   value
5. Start the virtual machine

You can then go to:

About this Mac -> System Report -> Hardware

and inspect that the Hardware UUID has changed.

Comment: For reference: https://kb.parallels.com/en/11197 - Also works for Parallels 16